# QT: Multi language support for the default TEXT in a Widget

Tags: c++, qt

How can I add multi language support for a default TEXT in a Widget?
For example, if I added a Button Widget from the GUI window (form) and set it default TEXT as 'Transfer' (in other words, this widget is in a '.ui' file), how can I add multi language support for it?

Where can I add the 'tr(Transfer)' transaction for it?

Comment: Please check the [Qt wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application/de).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I already read this wiki before. But, I did not see the solution for my case.

Comment: You can´t translate during compilation. The translation is done during runtime, so you have to translate the widgets at the application runtime.